# How to do AES256 decryption in PHP?

Tags: php, aes, mcrypt

I have an encrypted bit of text that I need to decrypt. It's encrypted with AES-256-CBC. I have the encrypted text, key, and iv. However, no matter what I try I just can't seem to get it to work.

The internet has suggested that mcrypt's Rijndael cypher should be able to do this, so here's what I have now:

```
function decrypt_data($data, $iv, $key) {
    $cypher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

    // initialize encryption handle
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cypher, $key, $iv) != -1) {
        // decrypt
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cypher, $data);

        // clean up
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cypher);
        mcrypt_module_close($cypher);

        return $decrypted;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As it stands now I get 2 warnings and the output is gibberish:

```
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init() [function.mcrypt-generic-init]: Key size too large; supplied length: 64, max: 32 in /var/www/includes/function.decrypt_data.php on line 8
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init() [function.mcrypt-generic-init]: Iv size incorrect; supplied length: 32, needed: 16 in /var/www/includes/function.decrypt_data.php on line 8
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with this stuff, but it seems like trying `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` in place of `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` would be an obvious next step...

**Edit:** You're right -- this isn't what you need. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is in fact the right choice.  According to the link you provided, your key and IV are twice as long as they should be:

```
// How do you do 256-bit AES encryption in PHP vs. 128-bit AES encryption???
// The answer is:  Give it a key that's 32 bytes long as opposed to 16 bytes long.
// For example:
$key256 = '12345678901234561234567890123456';
$key128 = '1234567890123456';

// Here's our 128-bit IV which is used for both 256-bit and 128-bit keys.
$iv =  '1234567890123456';
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. According to http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp that is the block size, not the key size.

Comment: Good catch.  The link you provided has the answer to your question:
You have to provide a 32 byte key, and a 16 byte IV.  You're passing in values that are twice as long as they need to be.

Comment: It turns out the were hex encoded and just needed to be run through `pack('H*', $var)`.

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb, but what exactly do you pack() ? Ive been trying to do this myself, without any luck..

Comment: @NilsMunch You use pack() to convert the Hex representation to the actual binary 128/256 bit representation.

Answer (score 1):

I send to you one example,
Please, check the code, ok

```
$data_to_encrypt = "2~1~000024~0910~20130723092446~T~00002000~USD~F~375019001012120~0~0~00000000000~";
$key128 = "abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789";
$iv = "0000000000000000";

$cc = $data_to_encrypt;
$key = $key128;
$iv =  $iv;
$length = strlen($cc);

$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,'','cbc','');

mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_generic($cipher,$cc));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cipher,base64_decode($encrypted));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

echo "encrypted: " . $encrypted;
echo "<br/>";
echo "length:".strlen($encrypted);
echo "<br/>";
echo "decrypted: " . substr($decrypted, 0, $length);
```

Comment: Worked for me! The only suggestion I have is to use rtrim instead of substr for the decrypted text since you may not always know the length. rtrim($decrypted, "\0")