# How to decrypt the iPhone encrypted AES256 text in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, encryption

I would like to know how to decrypt some text encrypted on iPhone using AES256 and PKCS7Padding with a PHP function.

I use following Objective-C code.

https://gist.github.com/838614

```
- (NSString *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
   NSData *plainData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

   NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData base64Encoding];

   return encryptedString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following PHP snippet covers [removing PKCS7 padding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mdecrypt-generic.php#89763), which combined with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628138/how-to-do-aes256-decryption-in-php) (but substituting `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` for `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` in your case) should give you what you need.

Comment: just a little question, in iOS code, we don't really have $iv kind of value in. what does it really mean.. and also about block size parameter to unpad.. thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: The IV in this case is the 6th argument to CCCrypt (line 48). More about IVs at Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector). The block size appears to be kCCBlockSizeAES128.