# How to decrypt AES256 in web(ASP)

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, asp-classic, aes

I'm making iphone app. 
I attempt to send to web(asp  ) encrypted password string from app.
I try to encrypt AES256 in app.
And have to decrypt this in web(asp  ).

I got source file to be able to encrypt using AES256. 
But I can't find the way to be able to decrypt in WEB(ASP...).

Can you tell me about the way to decrypt in WEB?

Comment: Are you defiantly working in a classic asp environment? If so, you’re going to have to resort to com/activex objects to manage the decryption, alternatively you could use php or asp.net to do this out of the box (pretty much). Can your webserver host .net or php?

Comment: Yes! I can't find com object for asp env as you say. So I try to change webserver host from asp to (.net or php ... java). :-)

Comment: If you had access to PHP, you can use mcrypt to perform the decryption, example question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628138/how-to-do-aes256-decryption-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You perform AES encryption and decryption in ASP, using Javascript directly, or using a COM object.

This page shows how to do AES crypto from Javascript.

http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/AES-Encryption.htm

The demo itself runs the javascript in a browser. I understand you want to run it in the server - in the ASP environment. It's just Javascript, it can run in either place.

Also, via Windows Script Components, you can package this AES crypto code as a COM component and then use it from any COM-friendly environment, like VB-ASP, VB6, Perl, or whatever.

For an example of that, See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/857903/48082