# How can I decrypt multiple .exe files in a directory using gpg?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

When I double click on a file PGP SDA asks for passphrase. I am able to decrypt files with a .gpg extension using this script:

```
gpg --batch --yes --passphrase 12345 --decrypt-files *.gpg
```

But when I run the above command with *.exe it gives me **unknown suffix** error.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with PowerShell? Are you trying to script this?

Comment: I will be writing a script to do this for all the .exe files in a particular directory.

Comment: Good stuff. You're in the right place for help with coding BUT at the moment this question looks more like "how do I use GPG"? Which is a bit off topic. The best way to get help on Stack Overflow is to start writing some code and ask (or search) precise questions as you hit each hurdle.

Comment: Enumerate the files and rename them to `.gpg` before decryption.

Comment: Changing the file type does not fix this. It gives an error saying **nothing is imported** when i try to open it.

Comment: Are you certain your .exe files are actually valid, gpg-encrypted, files? I just tested on my system, I get the same 'unknown suffix' error when running against .gpg files renamed to .exe, but when I change the name back to .gpg they work just fine.

Comment: If i double click on .exe files it opens a dialog for PGP SDA.
When i rename it to .gpg and run it gives me:
**gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found**
When i change it back to .exe it works fine.

Comment: SDA (self-decrypting archive) seems to be something [PGP-specific](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH149019.html), so it seems you either need PGP (rather than GnuPG) or somehow extract the actual encrypted data from the executable wrapper ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13960544/1630171)).